# Doctor and farmer

Tags: situation, family

That's the rule:

"A shepherd from Holland has a son doctor at London, the son doctor from London does not have a father shepherd from Holland".

How is this possible?

Comment: Because the shepherd is a female?

Answer (score 0):

Is this one of those biases one has while assuming genders .Like positions of power are considered to be male dominated and vice versa.
The Shepherd is the mother of the doctor

Comment: Haha, just beat me to the chase!

Answer (score 0):

The shepherd is a woman and therefore the doctor's mother.

Answer (score 0):

> The two doctors are two different people: The first guy is a shepherd's son from Holland and he is **at** London, and the other guy that he is also a doctor (and obviously someone's son) is **from** London.